# Como alterar os dados da Model que estão sendo mostrado em GridMvc?

Tags: c#, mvc, grid, viewmodel, model

Tenho uma GridMvc no meu formulario onde exibe uma lista de unidades, nesse grid tem um campo de texto, e um checkbox, gostaria de quando o usuario digitar alguma caixa de texto ou flagar o o check, essa mudança refletisse na model.

View:

```
     <b>Selecione as Unidades</b><div class="code-cut">
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(Columns =>
   {
       Columns.Add()
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .SetWidth(30)
                .RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("Selecionado", o.Selecionado));
       Columns.Add(c => c.IdUnidadeSAP).Titled("ID Unidade SAP").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.Codigo).Titled("ID Unidade Legado").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.Descricao).Titled("Desc. Unidade").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add(c => c.CodPrestadorSAP).Titled("Cod. Prestador SAP").Filterable(true);
       Columns.Add()
       .Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false)
       .SetWidth(30)
       .RenderValueAs(c => Html.TextBox("Cod. Prestador VAEL", c.TipoLogradouro));

   }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
    </div>
```

Tela:

[image: Tela do grid]

Comment: O que diz a documentação do componente sobre isso?

Comment: Não achei nada la que me ajudasse